# Google Artifact Registry custom URL

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

Using Google Artifact Registry (GAR), requires the usage of some "generic" URLs, like europe-west-1-docker.pkg/project-name/repository-name/image-name:tag.

We would like to use a custom URL so that complexity and project/region dependant naming is hidden.

A feature request seems to be in place for this for a couple of years now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212780766

Also, a private development attempts to address this by using a Proxy written in Go meant to run in CloudRun: https://github.com/ahmetb/serverless-registry-proxy/tree/master

We would prefer some more standard alternative, like having the ability to use nginx, but it seems like a dead end path.

Would you know/consider that it would be possible to use nginx to implement such custom urls for GAR considering that our repositories should be kept "private".

Comment: I would highly suggest, to file feature request again in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, there's no ETA. The Product Team will analyze if this said feature is applicable.

Comment: There is already [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212780766) created for ~1.5 years. Thing is, that a workaround while that happens would be great. Like the Go written proxy i linked, but that at least offers the possibility to "push" images too. If it could also be based on something more standard like haproxy/nginx/etc, that would be perfect.
I have (want) to believe it is me not being fluent enough with nginx, rather than GAR is so complicated to proxy :(